# Is it possible to cast a non-abstract ViewModel to another ViewModel that extends it?

Tags: android, mvvm, classcastexception, androidx, android-viewmodel

I am using a `ViewModel` to share data between `Fragments`. This `Fragment` is also used in multiple parts of the application. So I thought it’d be nice to define a non-abstract class that defined methods to be used by `ViewModels` that needed to use this `Fragment` allowing for simple shared `ViewModel` use. But I appear to be wrong...

When I try to cast the non-abstract “base" class to the `ViewModel` implementation class i receive a: `ClassCastException: com.project.viewmodel.NonAbstractBaseViewModel cannot be cast to com.project.viewmodel.ImplementationViewModel` runtime error.

My code that causes the `ClassCastException`:

```
// Scoping to the Activity because this is a shared ViewModel between Fragments.
ImplementationViewModel viewModel = (ImplementationViewModel) ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())
                                                                .get(NonAbstractBaseViewModel.class);
```

Is it possible to cast a `ViewModel`? Am I doing something wrong? Any input is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: NonAbstractBaseViewModel is your base view model?

Comment: Yes(not it’s really name..) but it’s a ViewModel that is extended by a few ViewModels that need to be shared between this fragment that is shared between multiple parts of my app. Hence why I tried to create a “base” class to make it so I would be able to work with one shared ViewModel in this fragments without having to keep track of several different ones that would need to be instantiated.

Comment: Your base class can not be cast into child class. Child can be cast in the base class.